# Rails complex hash structures in session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, hash

Is it possible to store complex hash structures inside the session?
Something like this:

```
session[:blabla] = {}
session[:blabla][:sub] = { :special => [], :xyz => {} }
```

When I reload the page, those variables get lost from the session.

edit1: I'm using Rails 2.3.x

edit2: If I save a simple hash inside the session, everything works fine.

Comment: Should be working. But please use try the following syntax instead: `session[:blabla] = { :sub => { :special => [], :xyz => {} } }`

Answer (score 1):

Well, it may be that the older version of rails is responsible for this.

If you want to save a deeply nested hash structure, you could try

```
session[:nestedstructure] = nested_hash.to_json
```

Of course, that depends on the objects being serializable with json.